# Is Spine-Leaf Network Topology dedicated only for Wired Connectivity?

Tags: topology

My Question is clear, so, is there an application of SL topology in wireless connectivity ?

If not, are there other topologies similar to that, having the same performances but for wireless purposes ?

Comment: Wireless uses a shared medium.

Comment: One of his disadvantages reside in the cables, but it can be used for several applications. So, i understand that no such deployment exists out the wired connection ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spine-leaf deals with multiple problems in networking, especially redundancy, performance, and scalability.

In a completely wireless network it would be next to impossible to achieve the same class of performance and scalability (and much more expensive than wired), so pratically you have to use a wired network for the higher tiers if you use wireless in the access tier.

(Of course, common wireless equipment can't compete mit 10G+ wired networking but that doesn't rule out the existence of proprietary = expensive solutions.)

Comment: Thank you Zac. I was looking for a wireless topologies (that have some advantages in Fog Computing environment), unfortunately, Spine-Leaf do not much in this context (so because, there isn't a clear vision on the topologies employed at the Fog Layer)